# How to pass data from Android to Laravel

Tags: android, laravel

I'm currently working on an android project. In this project, I pass data name, message, and email to the server through a simple PHP code. But now I want to pass these data to the server through Laravel, because the project is in Laravel.

Android data

```
String name     = params[1];
String message  = params[2];
String mail     = params[3];
```

And pass this data to Laravel. Here is the code. The folder in which this file is present.  Apps/Http/  . Now how we write the android code to pass this data to route easily.

```
Route::get('/message/{userid}','MapController@sendalert');
Route::post('/mymessage','MapController@myalert');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you already know how to post since you can post to "simple php". Now what you want is build an API with Laravel. Once ready you can post your data to a URL rather than a php file, like

```
POST
https://www.mywebsite.com/api/comments
```

And your controller will take over. There are several steps involved in this process with a lot of resources available online like these:
http://esbenp.github.io/2016/04/11/modern-rest-api-laravel-part-1/
https://www.codetutorial.io/laravel-5-rest-api-basic-authentication/

Those should get you started.

Comment: Have a look at this android library. It might help: http://square.github.io/retrofit/